# Is it possible to limit port number reservation range in GlassFish (or underlying jvm machine)?

Tags: java, linux, glassfish, port

In a Linux server where I have a few GlassFish instances we want to start another server product and had an "Address already in use" error.

Investigating with `lsof` we found that a java process of GlassFish was occupying port number needed by the second product we want to run in the same machine.

Is there a way to limit port reservation range for GlassFish (or underlying jvm machine)?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You don't need to 'limit port number reservation range', you need  to control the actual ports that are used.

Comment: What I found with lsof command is that Java processus open ports dynamically, that are not defined in control panel or xml configuration files. The problem is that we don't want some ports to be used.

Answer (score 0):

GlassFish uses a few ports and you need to tell him to use some other ports. Then you should be able to run it.

```
asadmin set server.http-service.http-listener.http-listener-1.port=10080
asadmin set server.http-service.http-listener.http-listener-2.port=10443
asadmin set server.http-service.http-listener.admin-listener.port=14848
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.system-property.JMS_PROVIDER_PORT.value=9999
```

Look here for more info: https://arnoldvillasanta.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/changing-default-glassfish-v3-port-numbers-4848-8080-and-8181/

Comment: What I found with lsof command is that Java processus open ports dynamically, that are not defined in control panel or xml configuration files. The problem is that we don't want some ports to be used.